# Cancel Oracle procedure from SQL Server procedure when cancelled

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures, linked-server, cancellation

I'm executing a stored procedure on the SQL Server side. In some part of this procedure, a remote Oracle procedure is called using

```
execute ('
begin 
    oraprocname(procparams); 
end;')
at remotedb.
```

Today, I needed to stop executing this procedure so I have used cancel query on SQL Server side.

The problem is that SQL Server was not able to stop the procedure until the remote procedure was stopped (I needed to kill it from remotedb side).

Is there any way to somehow "inform" the Oracle side that the procedure needs to be cancelled from a stored procedure on the SQL Server side?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that once you've sent a command to Oracle, it will not return until the end of the command.

So unless `execute () at remotedb` has specific parameters that would wrap the call in a sub-process that can be stopped by the caller (unlikely, but why not?), you must create your own Oracle function that will kill your long-running session.

So my solution is you create another Oracle function or procedure to kill your long-running session, and call it from a separate process.

Get your running sessions:

```
select
  sid
  , serial#
from
  v$session
where
      username='<your user>'
  and status = 'ACTIVE'
```

Then use above info to kill it, using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ALTER SYSTEM`:

```
begin
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SYSTEM kill session ''<sid>,<serial#>'' ';
end;
/
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for reply. The problem is that I don't have an access to global views like v$session... My user on Oracle site has only read rights and exec ones for several procedures :/

Comment: Then you may need to have such a procedure created for you on the remote db, and execute permission granted to your user.